# Problem PXE booting

Tags: kernel, pxe

In relation to [dist-upgrade of diskless ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184276/dist-upgrade-of-diskless-ubuntu).

I have upgraded my diskless image to 12.04. I've updated the the default file in my tftpboot server, but whenever i boot the server, it comes with the error message "Could not find kernel image: precise/vmlinuz

I did try to cp the files into the `/var/lib/tftboot/precise/` folder, and got it booting, but would really like for the symlinks to work. What am i doing wrong?

`/var/lib/tftpboot/precise/default`:

> LABEL precise
>
> KERNEL precise/vmlinuz
>
> APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=precise/initrd.img ip=dhcp >nfsroot=192.168.2.3:/q/system/precise ro pci=noacpi ipv6.disable=1 panic=10

symlink is made with the following command:
`sudo ln -s /q/system/precise/vmlinuz`

Same is done for initrd.img

EDIT:
The problem was resolved after creating a new debootstrap image to boot from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from a comment in another question that you had a file permission error that prevented reading the files. You're now having issues with your nfs mount.

Can you please update this question regarding the permissions and your new NFS problem. I'll need the contents of the relevant pxelinux.cfg file, /etc/exports and the output of showmount -e.

Comment: Hi Johnf. I got it working. I ended up having some really wired issues, about not beeing able to connect to the Dbus, so i ended up making a new debootstrap, in accordance with this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto and it seems to be working now. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone faces the same problem.
I had the same problem, but the problem was that I didn't have the correct permissions. Use following command for your folder to get it to work.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
```

Comment: That is not the brightest move. As that gives every user on your system permission to edit those files. It works, but 755 would be better, as users just need to read the files, but not edit them..